# Show that $M$ is compact $\Leftrightarrow$ every real continuous positive function has positive infimum

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I already proved the first statement:

If $M$ is compact $\Rightarrow$ every positive continuous function $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has positive infimum.

Now, I need to prove the converse: If $M$ is a metric space such that every positive continuous function $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has positive infimum, so $M$ is compact.

I found this question here: [$M$ is compact iff $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ has a positive infimum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462862/m-is-compact-iff-fm-to-mathbbr-has-a-positive-infimum)

But I want to prove this without using pseudocompactness, and this question uses.
Can someone just give me some hints? I really don't want the answer itself.

Comment: Maybe something like the second answer of this question should work changing $\inf$ by $\sup$ or $1/n$ by $n$ in the definition of $g$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244557/existence-of-a-continuous-function-which-does-not-achieve-a-maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with no convergent subsequence the  $E=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ is  a closed set. Define $f:E\to (0,1) $ by $f(x_n)=\frac 1 n$. Then $f$ is continuous. By (one form of) Tietze Extension Theorem there exists a continuous function  $F:X \to (0,1)$ such that $F=f$ on $E$. This continuous function does not have  a positive  infimum. [I can  provide more information on Tietze's Theorem if needed].